# On Facebook share URL, give option to user to choose image

Tags: facebook, share

I don't see the answer I'm looking for, so hopefully someone can help.

I have a PHP script, which displays data from an SQL database.  The dynamic elements are pulled in, essentially showing details of a job listing.  On this page, I have a Facebook share URL.

Example:

```
<a title="Post on Facebook"
   href="http://www.facebook.com/share.php?u=http://www.mywebsite.com/joblisting/details.php?job_id=1345488636.3750">
   POST ON FACEBOOK
</a>
```

When the user clicks that link, they get the Facebook page to post this to their Facebook page.  The page they are on pre-populates with my page title, page description, etc.

And if I have an image on my page, that becomes the default thumbnail image for the FB post.  I also set a defualt Facebook image in my metatag, and that works too.  I also added up to 10 other images on my page, so that the user could choose from 1 of 10 images as the default thumbnail.  But...

**I wanted to be able to let the user choose a thumbnail image from their desktop.  Is this possible?**

Answer (score 0):

The image that's used in the Share dialog needs to exist somewhere on the web before the dialog is invoked, so you'd need to allow the user to upload it somewhere before popping the dialog in order to do what you're suggesting.